# How to make scrollable table body occupy available screen height

Tags: css

I have a page consisting of a header, a footer and a table with a scrollable body.

I'm trying to get all the content to take up exactly 100vh, with the table body being scrollable if contains to many rows to fit.

So far I have this jsfiddle, but I'm defining the table body's height, which I want to avoid:

https://jsfiddle.net/134asedk/3/

Can I get the table body to resize based on the available remaining space using CSS only? I'd prefer not to use `flexbox`, but I can use a fallback if flexbox seems to be the best way.

[edit] I need to support IE10, so I can't use calc as suggested in a couple of otherwise great answers below.

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm scratching my head.

Answer (score 6):

Use `calc()` function in css to effectively calculate the `height` so as to adjust both footer and header and the table height.

```
tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100vh - 200px );
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zjfq5z8/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm supporting IE10, and I've just seen that calc isn't supported. I'll update my question to include IE10 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a responsive height for a fullbody element via css, you will only find false workaround.

But if you want, you can take the window width and window height and set them on your table via javascript!

To be more responsive as possible, you can do this on window resize too ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use `height: calc(100% - 140px); overflow-y: scroll;` on `.table-wrapper`. `140px` is the height + top/bottom padding of `.header-wrapper` and `.footer-wrapper`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-wrapper, .footer-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  height: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table; 
  table-layout: fixed;  
}

th, td {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-aligh: left;
  
}

span {
  float: left;
}

/*tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}*/

.table-wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span>Table Head1</span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>Table Head 2</span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>Table Head 3</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 1</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 2</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>Cell 3</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <h1>The footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm supporting IE10, and I've just seen that calc isn't supported. I'll update my question to include IE10 support.